# Turtle racing game - unable to keep turtle on square

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

Me and my friend are currently coding an exercise in school and we met difficulties with how to make the turtles keep on track. To illustrate, for the first side of the square, 2 turtles are racing on the sides. However, when they turn 90 degrees, 1 or 2 of them will get off the sides, which is incorrect with respect to the exercise requirements.

Here is our code:

```
import turtle
from random import randint
def read_int(prompt,first,last):
    x = int(input(prompt))
    while x < first or x > last:
        print("Not in range. Try Again!!!")
        x= int(input(prompt))
    return x

square_count = read_int("Enter your laps between 1 and 10: ",1,10)
print(square_count)
#def t():

window = turtle.Screen()
window.bgcolor('lightblue')
def draw_square(turtle, center, size):
    xPt, yPt = center
    xPt -= size / 2
    yPt += size / 2
    side = 4
    size = 300
    angle = 90
    turtle.speed(0)
    turtle.up()
    turtle.goto(xPt, yPt)
    turtle.down()
    for i in range(side):
        turtle.forward(size)
        turtle.right(angle)

t = turtle.Turtle()
draw_square(t,(0,0),300)
t.shape('turtle')
t.color("red")
t.pensize(5)
t.up()
t.goto(-150, 150)

#def r():
r = turtle.Turtle()
draw_square(r,(0,0),300)
r.shape('turtle')
r.color("yellow")
r.up()
r.pensize(5)
r.goto(-150, 150)

sides = 4
size = 300


count_int = int(square_count)* sides
if count_int > 1:
    for sides in range(count_int):
            i = 0
            e = 0
            while i in range(0, size) or e in range(0, size):
                t_step = randint(1, 5)
                t.forward(t_step)
                i = i + t_step
                r_step = randint(1, 5)
                r.forward(r_step)
                e = e + r_step

            t.right(90)
            r.right(90)





window.exitonclick()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake lies towards the end of your program.

```
while i in range(0, size) or e in range(0, size):
                t_step = randint(1, 5)
                t.forward(t_step)
                i = i + t_step
                r_step = randint(1, 5)
                r.forward(r_step)
                e = e + r_step
```

In a scenario where lets say i = 298, and t_step chooses a random integer as 3. The turtle will end up moving greater than the range of 300, thereby it moves outside the drawn box. **The loop does not stop as it only realizes that i is out of range when all the code has been run. (i.e The turtle has already moved outside the box by the time the loop is broken.)** That is why the turtles goes outside. You could maybe try using an 'if' condition to  prevent this.

Answer (score 0):

You have two kind of problems. 
First of all you should care attention on how much steps your turtles take. Because if a square is of size 300 it might happen that a turtle took a quantity of steps that their sum isn't equal to 300. I suggest you to change the generation of random steps to:

```
steps = random.randrange(0, 4, 2)
```

In this way a turtle could take only 0 or 2 steps and you are sure that the sum will bring you to 300. 
The second point is maybe more important. If you structure the *race loop* as you did, a turtle will turn only if the other turtle has reached the end of a line, you should reorganize your code to make the two turtles independend one from the other.

Comment: Ok!! Thanks for your advice :)

Answer (score 0):

I would take a slightly different approach -- instead of hardcoding two turtles, design for any number of turtles and then just race two turtles. Here's a rewrite based on any number of turtles, including some rework of the code for style, plus some code suggestions by @Claudio:

```
from random import randint
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
from collections import defaultdict

SIZE = 300
SIDES = 4
ANGLE = 90
MAXIMUM_STRIDE = 5

COLORS = ('red', 'gold', 'green', 'orange', 'blue')

MAX_RACERS = len(COLORS)

def read_int(prompt, first, last):
    x = int(input(prompt))

    while not first <= x <= last:
        print('Not in range! Try Again.')
        x = int(input(prompt))

    return x

def draw_square(turtle, center, size):
    xPt, yPt = center

    xPt -= size / 2
    yPt += size / 2

    turtle.up()
    turtle.goto(xPt, yPt)
    turtle.down()

    for _ in range(SIDES):
        turtle.forward(SIZE)
        turtle.right(ANGLE)

lap_count = read_int('Enter number of laps (between 1 and 10): ', 1, 10)
no_racers = read_int('Enter number of racers (between 2 and {}): '.format(MAX_RACERS), 2, MAX_RACERS)

jockey_colors = COLORS[0:no_racers]

window = Screen()
window.bgcolor('lightblue')

racers = defaultdict(dict)

draw_square(Turtle(visible=False), (0, 0), SIZE)

for color in jockey_colors:
    jockey = Turtle('turtle', visible=False)
    jockey.speed('fastest')
    jockey.color(color)

    jockey.up()
    jockey.goto(-SIZE/2, SIZE/2)
    jockey.showturtle()

    racers[color]['jockey'] = jockey
    racers[color]['sides'] = 0
    racers[color]['position'] = 0

finished = False

while not finished:
    for racer in racers.values():
        jockey = racer['jockey']

        step = randint(1, MAXIMUM_STRIDE + 1)

        if racer['position'] + step > SIZE:

            racer['sides'] += 1

            if racer['sides'] == lap_count * SIDES:
                finished = True
                break

            baby_step = SIZE - racer['position']
            jockey.forward(baby_step)
            jockey.right(ANGLE)
            racer['position'] = 0

            step -= baby_step

        jockey.forward(step)
        racer['position'] += step

window.exitonclick()
```

Comment: As my exercise requires 2 turtle should run on the same square. Therefore, I cannot apply this solution. However, thank you for your support. It helps me a lot!!!

Comment: @davidmechin, I've simplified the code to use a single shared square.

Comment: The code as originally provided (see the code in the answer by Claudio -
 it doesn't care about it) has TWO sources of randomness. The first, the intended, is to make the step length random. Another, overseen in the heat of creating the algorithm, a shortening of the step depending on the distance to the corner of the square at the turn point. It was there because the algorithm was skipping to move the racer forward the remaining distance (if any). As THIS answer tends to provide a "better" turtle game I have proposed an improved version to be listed in this answer.

Comment: @Claudio, I've incorporated your suggestions.  I can't say the "randomness" issue makes much of a difference but better to make it explicit.  Choosing the number of racers, since the code can handle it, is a nice option.

Answer (score -1):

Here you are:

```
import turtle

from random import randint

def read_int(prompt,first,last):
    x = int(input(prompt))
    while x < first or x > last:
        print("Not in range. Try Again!!!")
        x= int(input(prompt))
    return x

no_of_laps = read_int("Enter your laps between 1 and 10: ",1 , 10)
print(no_of_laps)

window = turtle.Screen()

window.bgcolor('lightblue')

def draw_square(turtle, center, size):
    xPt, yPt = center
    xPt -= size / 2
    yPt += size / 2
    side = 4
    size = 300
    angle = 90
    turtle.speed(0)
    turtle.up()
    turtle.goto(xPt, yPt)
    turtle.down()
    for i in range(side):
        turtle.forward(size)
        turtle.right(angle)

t = turtle.Turtle()
draw_square(t,(0,0),300)

t.shape('turtle')
t.color("red")
t.pensize(5)
t.up()
t.goto(-150, 150)

#def r():
r = turtle.Turtle()
draw_square(r,(0,0),300)
r.shape('turtle')
r.color("yellow")
r.up()
r.pensize(5)
r.goto(-150, 150)

sides = 4
size  = 300

no_of_turns = int(no_of_laps) * sides

countTurns_t = 0
countTurns_r = 0
t_i = 0
r_i = 0

while countTurns_t < no_of_turns and countTurns_r < no_of_turns: 


    t_step = randint(1, 5)
    if t_i + t_step > size:
        t_step = size - t_i
        t.forward(t_step)
        t_i = 0
        t.right(90)
        countTurns_t += 1
    else:
        t.forward(t_step)
        t_i += t_step

    r_step = randint(1, 5)
    if r_i + r_step > size:
        r_step = size - r_i
        r.forward(r_step)
        r_i = 0
        r.right(90)
        countTurns_r += 1
    else:
        r.forward(r_step)
        r_i += r_step

window.exitonclick()
```

P.S. hope you can see how and why this code provided above works as expected. Read carefully the other answers, they point out important issues you were missing writing your code.